# Cordova: HTTP requests seem to be blocked on android (production) application

Tags: android, cordova

I published yesterday a Cordova application on the Android market (aka Google Play Store) and I noticed a weird bug that I can't reproduce in dev environment.

In fact, all the HTTP requests seem to be blocked by the application (The Ads won't show, the inline images in the articles won't show, the video won't load, etc).

I properly set the access origin to "*" in my config.xml file and when I take a look at the app permissions I see it can receive information from the Internet. Of course the application works properly when I build/install it from my computer.

Also I don't see how I could fix this or even start debugging it.
Have you got any idea how I could debug this ?

Thanks

NB: The apps works great on iOS devices (dev and prod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue.

The problem was that I removed the plugin jsHybugger (before building and signing the app) with the following command

```
cordova plugin rm org.jshybugger.cordova
```

and did not regenerate the android platform afterward.

So I just did

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

and all went fine.

Apparently Cordova keeps some files of plugins even after they're removed from the project. I guess those jsHybugger calls where making something crash on my app (because the plugin wasn't there anymore)...

NB: To debug the production version of my app, I simply installed the corresponding apk (found in platforms/android/bin/MY_PROD_APP.apk) on my phone (the one I sent to Google Play Store)